# How does dependencies isolation between MongoDB and Django work?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, dependencies, database

How does Isolation dependencies between mongdb and django work?

I have made several projects with JAVA/SPRING, and the recent days, 
I am studying Python django .

I successed to get connection between django and sqlite, and few days ago, 
when I tried to connect to mongodb, it is hard to seperate dependencies database and django because of django-admin.

Django-admin require to attain specific Fields to each model, however, every database has each their own Field properties. Therefore, when project should change database structure, we should change a lot of code in model.py.

e.g

**What if sqlite to Mongodb? only using different driver cannot make server work. e.g models.TextField(sqlite) -> models.StringField(mongodb). It is unavoidable, right? It seems difficult that solating dependencies completely between database and django**

Is it Okay? do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What if sqlite to Mongodb? only using different driver cannot make server work. e.g models.TextField(sqlite) -> models.StringField(mongodb). It is unavoidable, right? It seems difficult that solating dependencies completely between database and django

`TextField` and `StringField` isn't where you will have problems since it is supported in almost all databases, but consider this library [django-mongodb-engine](http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), it reuses the basic fields that already exist in Django ORM to the extent of what's possible, e.g.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField() <-- both Django ORM and mongodb-engine have this
    text = models.TextField()  <-- both Django ORM and mongodb-engine have this
```

This model will work as is both in SQL and MongoDB engines, but if you use a MongoDB-only (as in not in default Django ORM engine) feature like `ListField()`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = ListField() # <-- not supported everywhere
```

Then you migration to a SQL engine will involve some manual work to map that field.

> Therefore, when project should change database structure, we should change a lot of code in `models.py`. Is it Okay?

Typically yes, to change the database structure you make changes in `models.py`. After which you would be running a [*migration*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/), which is a step that generates scripts to alter the database (e.g. adding a new SQL table column). For MongoDB there's no explicit migration, as its schema is flexible (or *schemaless* if you prefer).

As for the admin, it's fairly smart when it comes to Django models, you may need to define the models and fields you want to appear in the admin, but in the detail view you don't have to worry about every single field, as Django admin understands them based on the information in `models.py`

And to change database drivers, it's the `DATABASES` value in `settings.py`

Comment: Thank you very much for this rich helpful guide and information again . I should study harder with your links.